# Navigation Property in EF Core is NULL

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

Can someone guide me on how to construct the proper property navigation on the below tables?

I have these tables in my database:

[image]

[image]

I then need to relate the `Status` table to get the status `Name` on every table

[image]

These are my model classes:

```
[Table("Companies")]
public class CompanyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Status_Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }

    public DateTime Updated_Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

[Table("Customers")]
public class CustomerEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status_Id { get; set; }
```

}

```
[Table("Status")]
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to when I get all the `Companies` or `Customers` using `DBContext` e.g. `var companies = _dbContext.Companies.ToList()`. I want to get the status of every record for `Companies` and `Customers`. I'm not so sure how to construct the navigation property properly for the said models.

TIA!

**Update #1**

After following the below suggestion, yes the `Status` is not `NULL` anymore. But, it gets the wrong status id. Instead of using the `Status_Id`, it uses the `Id` of the Company. Please see below snippets. The status of the said company is `6`.

[image]

But if you notice on the 2nd snip, the status is `3` which is the `Id` of the Company.
[image]

I also have this code in `OnModelCreating`.

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
                .HasOne<Status>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.Status_Id);
```

This is the reason why I get that behavior. But if I removed this, the `Status` property is gets `NULL`.

**Update #2**

Just fixed my issue. I need to change the `Company` property from `public Company Company { get;set; } to` public List Companies { get;set; }`. Then add the suggested answer` Include`.

```
[Table("Status")]
public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `.Include()` method to join your status table in your result like so:

`_dbContext.Companies.Include(c => c.Status).ToList()`

Comment: please see my update in the original question. Thanks!